# Xampp localhost loads but XAMPP's Apache can not start while another webserver is using port 80 on OSX 10.8.4

Tags: php, macos, apache

This is so contradicting, connecting to `http://localhost`. opens up `http://localhost/xampp/` but at the same time Apache via Xampp control panel shows that it is stopped and won't start. It gives me the following error:

**Another webserver is already running!**

XAMPP's Apache can not start while another webserver is using port 80. Please turn it off and try again.

Unsure what to make of this, if Xampp's Apache cannot start then how are the sites under Xampp htdocs load as well as localhost goes to Xampp's internal page.

Here is a snapshot

[image]

Any clues will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed this complete question but then decided to try one classic solution. I quit Xampp control panel and initiated the application again so this time it showed me this

[image]

Which is pretty weird because I did nothing but just close and start the program again. Not even restarted my Apache via command line or anything. Thus seems like a bug in Xampp on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this bug. I had to restart my computer in order to make the Apache server stop. It seems to work fine this then.